# Appium, iOS, and purchasing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appium

It looks like appium uses Instruments to communicate with iOS devices. Instruments requires the build on the iOS device to be a development build. However, purchases cannot be made on development builds, only adhoc builds. This means that Instruments cannot connect to an app that has purchasing enabled, which in turn means that appium cannot connect to an app that has purchasing enabled.

Is this a known issue, and is there any known workaround?

Comment: Why do you say purchases can't be made on development builds?  You need to use a sandbox iTunes account, but you can test in-app purchase